# My Aspect doesn't initialize properties from yaml file

Tags: java, spring, yaml, aspect

I have Aspect class that need to calculate something in its method. It has to obtain values from yaml file. I am trying to run it for example with unit test. The application.yaml is in src/test/resources. As i debugging it I have noticed that when the method is triggered , the fields are not initialized, they are NULL. All other classes reading the values from the file fine. What can be the problem here ?

```
@Value("${enabled:true}")
private boolean enabled;

public Aspect() {
    LOGGER.info(Aspect.class.getName() + " aspect initialized ");
}


@Before("within(services..*) && @annotation(resolver)")
public void resolver(JoinPoint joinPoint, R resolver){

When we are here the values from the fields are null .

}
```

Also when i add @PostConstruct init method. Its working fine.

```
@PostConstruct
public void init() {
      LOGGER.info(" enabled :: " + enabled);

} //This prints true
```

Comment: have you tried defining property source explicitly using @PropertySource("application.yaml") ??

Comment: Yes, i have tried. The same result.